# Inserting into two database tables, parent and child, not working, likely something small

Tags: php, html, mysql

If anyone can point me to a similar solution, I initally had only one table (Dog) with basic data and one profile img.

I decided I would make an extra table, that will have the dogId as a FK for additional images.

My code works perfect if I keep the tables separate. When I create the FK in the images table, the code will not insert any data into the DB. I think the issue is something small.

i have two database tables, one is for a Dog includes name , age, gender etc and one profile image.

The second is the new table, for additional images, with a foreign key of dog Id in order to reference the dog the additional images belong to.

The issue i am having is, the basic upload of a dog profile was working perfect (uploading one main image and data, and entering into the database).

I made a new table for additional image uploads, and put a foreign key of the main Dog table into it. (id). this was to reference the dog the additional pics belong to.

I amended the code to include an additional form element:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="extra_images">Choose Images</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" 
     name="userfile[]" value="" multiple="">
                </div>
```

It will not upload to either table now, or show the multi images on the show_dog page (included last in code)

I am not sure if I am referencing the Foreign key correctly, or inserting that part correct. this could relate to:

```
 $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO dog_img (name, img_dir, id) VALUES('$name', 
'$img_dir', '$id')";
```

which is in the Functions section for:

```
 if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){......

 //CODE BELOW


 <form class="" action="create_dog.php" method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" <? 
 php echo $name ?> placeholder="Enter Name" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="age">Age:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" 
   placeholder="Enter Age" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" 
   placeholder="Enter Gender" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="breed">Breed</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="breed" 
  placeholder="Enter Breed" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="description">Description</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  name="description" placeholder="Enter a Description" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="image">Choose Image</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" 
  value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="extra_images">Choose Images</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" 
     name="userfile[]" value="" multiple="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" name="create_dog_btn" value 
      ="upload" class="btn btn-primary waves">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




  //functions

  if (isset($_POST['create_dog_btn'])) {
  create_new_dog();
 }

 function create_new_dog(){

  global $conn;
  global $upload_dir;


  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_GET['id']));
   echo $id;
   $sql = "SELECT * from dog where id=".$id;
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   }else {
     $errorMsg = 'Could not Find Any Record';
   }
  }
  //validation....... (cut out for tidyness sake)
  if(empty($errors)){

        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgName, 
                  PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $allowExt  = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

        $userPic = time().'_'.rand(1000,9999).'.'.$imgExt;

        if(in_array($imgExt, $allowExt)){

            if($imgSize < 5000000){
                move_uploaded_file($imgTmp 
                   ,$upload_dir.$userPic);
            }else{
                $errors[] = 'Image too large';

            }
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Please select a valid image';
        }
    }
      elseif(!empty($errors)){

      foreach ($errors as $msg) {
              echo "- $msg <br/>";
      }
      echo "<h4><br/>Please enter correct details!</h4>";
     }
if(!isset($errors)){


        $sql = "INSERT INTO dog(name, age, gender, breed,  
         description, image)
                values('".$name."', '".$age."', 
        '".$gender."', '".$breed."', '".$description."', 
  '".$userPic."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result){
            $successMsg = 'New dog added successfully';
            header('Location: index_admin.php');
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'Error adding this record. 
          '.mysqli_error($conn);
    if(!empty($errors)){
      foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                  echo "- $msg <br/>";
          }
      //echo $errorMsg[];
    }
        }
    }
     }

      function reArrayFiles($file_post){
      $file_ary = array();
      $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
      $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for($i=0; $i < $file_count; $i ++){
        foreach($file_keys as $key){
        $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
    }
        return $file_ary;
    }


      if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){

   $phpFileUploadsErrors = array(
    0=> 'there is no error, the fle uploaded with success',
    1=> 'the file exceeds the upload max file size in php ini',
    2=> 'the file exceeds the upload max file size specified in HTML 
    form',
    3=> 'uploaded file only partially uploaded',
    4=> 'no file was uploaded',
    5=> 'missing a temporary folder',
    6=> 'failed to write file to disk',
    7=> 'a php extension stopped the file upload',
  );
  $file_array = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userfile']);
  pre_r($_FILES);
  for($i=0; $i<count($file_array); $i++){

   if($file_array[$i]['error']){
     ?> <div class = "alert alert-danger">
    <?php echo $file_array[$i]['name'].' - 
 '.$phpFileUploadsErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
    ?> </div> <?php
   }
   else{

  $extensions = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');

  $file_ext = explode('.', $file_array[$i]['name']);
  //pre_r( $file_ext); die;
  //image name variable at index 0 as per associative arrays
  $name = $file_ext[0];
  $name = preg_replace("!-!"," ", $name);
  $name = ucwords($name);

  $file_ext = end($file_ext);


  //convert any uppercase extensions to lowercase whilst checking valid 
   extension
  if(!in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $extensions)){
    ?> <div class = "alert alert-danger">
   <?php echo "{$file_array[$i]['name']} Invalid file extension!";
   ?> </div> <?php
  }
  else{
   $img_dir = "../uploads/".$file_array[$i]['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($file_array[$i]['tmp_name'],$img_dir);

    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO dog_img (name, img_dir, id) 
 VALUES('$name', 
'$img_dir', '$id')";
   $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
   ?> <div class = "alert alert-success">
  <?php echo $file_array[$i]['name'].' - 
 '.$phpFileUploadsErrors[$file_array[$i]['error']];
  ?> </div> <?php

      }
    }
  }

  } //END OF FUNCTIONS



  //SHOW DOG THE MULTI UPLOAD IMAGES WILL NOT DISPLAY

    <div class="card-header">
         SHOW DOG
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$row['image'] ?>" 
  height="200">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <h5 class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-user-tag">
                  <span><?php echo $row['name'] ?></span>
                </i></h5>
                <h5 class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-mobile-alt">
                  <span><?php echo $row['age'] ?></span>
                </i></h5>
                <h5 class="form-control"><i class="fa fa-mobile-alt">
                  <span><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></span>
                </i></h5>
                <h5 class="form-control"><i class="fas fa-dog">
                  <span><?php echo $row['breed'] ?></span>
                </i></h5>
                <h5 class="form-control"><i class="fas fa-dog">
                  <span><?php echo $row['description'] ?></span>
                </i></h5>

                  <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
 href="index_admin.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i> 
 <span>Back</span></a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
          $result = $conn-> query("SELECT * FROM dog_img") or die($conn- 
 >error);
          echo "test";
          while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "<h2>{$data['name']} </h2>";
          echo "<img src='{$data['img_dir']}' width ='40%' 
  height='40%'>";
          }

      ?>
   </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I accept my code is very long, but I am really stuck with this.

thank you.

Comment: Several points!
1. you shouldn't build SQL queries like this. It's insecure.
2. you should separate HTML and PHP with a template engine
3. you should always post [minimal, complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code!

Comment: in your insert into 'dog' query, the values ($name,$age etc)are never defined the values you want are in the post array

Comment: I provided the code to back up my question... I think my issue is inserting the data into two tables in separate functions.. but I dont know for sure..

Comment: You should make debug outputs, or log somewhere, to see what your SQL statement exactly is when executing it!

Comment: do the images get uploaded and stored on the server? , i think your defining the `value=''` on your upload selection.

Comment: Only uploaded if I remove the foreign key contraint in the images table. works fine, but then on the show page, all extra images show for all the dogs, and not specific to the dog ID. I just removed the FK and all uploading fine to both tables, but not related.

Comment: I know it is somehting really small. Its just figuring out how to have the foreign key ID inserted  in the images table, and then display the images pertaining to that ID,

Comment: Okay, assign a random key on every dog on registration and then, on uploading more images, call that key and `session ` it and save it along with the uploaded images. to call the images relate to that saved key. That way may be eased.

Comment: do you mean to avoid using a FK altogether and just use sessions?

Comment: I decided to place the additional images upload onto the SHOW page  for admin, and I have it working fine, using the FK and matching :) thank you for your help